# itextsharp, issue with PDFtable constructor

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

In all the tutorials about tables I have found code like this:

```
PdfTable table = new PdfTable(5);
```

But in my case ***"PdfTable has no constructor"***. So any single tutorial, works for me.

Has any one solved this issue? I know it is quite common.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you need is `PdfPTable`, not `PdfTable` (mind the extra P). Please let me know if you have found a tutorial where it says:

```
PdfTable table = new PdfTable(5);
```

I will personally contact the author trying to convince him to stop publishing non sense ;-)

`PdfTable` used to be a class in a very old version of iTextSharp ([a version that should no longer be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially/25698526#25698526)). It was an internal helper class for the no longer existing `Table` class. You were not supposed to instantiate it (hence the message "PdfTable has no constructor").

For examples on using the `PdfPTable` class, see http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C04

Comment: Very common misconception. I battled with this one too a while ago